# git checkout is auto-completing all branches (including remote)

Tags: git

When I run `git checkout` and hit tab to autocomplete, it suggests all branches, both local and remote.  It used to only show me the local branches.  I'm not sure what I did to change this behavior - maybe it is a config somewhere?  I'd like to change it back so that `git checkout` only suggests local branches by default.

Comment: You need to modify your `git-completion.bash` script, typically stored in `/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash`.

Comment: I'm using zsh on a Mac and this is where the file was for me: `/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.15.1/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash`

Comment: OK, so did you modify to suit your needs?